# Write data "by chunks" into OpenCL buffer

Tags: multithreading, gpu, opencl, read-write

I'm working on porting a CUDA application to OpenCL and I noticed that CUDA offers the functionality of writing data to its "buffers" by chunks. What I mean by this is the following:

```
int *vals = new int[N/4];
int *d_vec = nullptr;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_vec, sizeof(int) * N);
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    cudaMemcpy(d_vec + i*(N/4), vals, sizeof(int) * N/4, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

What the code above does is to write the `vals` array (which has 1/4 of the `d_vec` buffer) sequentially to `d_vec`. So my question is, is it possible to do the same with OpenCL? That is, allocate a buffer and write values sequentially to it, without having to write an array with the full buffer size?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a size and offset for [clEnqueueWriteBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_API.html#clEnqueueWriteBuffer), which would be your replacement for the `cudaMemcpy`.

```
cl_int clEnqueueWriteBuffer(
    cl_command_queue command_queue,
    cl_mem buffer,
    cl_bool blocking_write,
    size_t offset, // from your example: i*(N/4)
    size_t size,   // from your example: sizeof(int) * N/4
    const void* ptr,
    cl_uint num_events_in_wait_list,
    const cl_event* event_wait_list,
    cl_event* event);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is indeed possible with `enqueueWriteBuffer`:

```c
cl_int *vals = new cl_int[N/4];
Buffer d_vec;
d_vec = Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, N*sizeof(cl_int));
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(d_vec, true, i*(N/4), sizeof(cl_int)*N/4, (void*)vals);
    queue.finish();
}
```